# How to make a text-box partially readonly using Knockoutjs/HTML attribue?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS to make a text box that contains some read-only text at the beginning of the text box and then allows editing following the read-only text. How can I do this?

Here is the code snippet i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    var field = document.getElementById('waNumberField');
    var readOnlyLength = field.value.length;

    field.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        var which = event.which;
        if (((which == 8) && (field.selectionStart <= readOnlyLength)) 
            || ((which == 46) && (field.selectionStart < readOnlyLength))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
        else {
            // field.unbind('keydown');
            //return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code or an example of your attempt to solve this problem. For reference see: [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For example, a textbox having default value say "+1",which is readonly and else part need to enter values.

Answer (score 1):

I created jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u1jn8mqh/ where you can see an expected output. Is it right?
In HTML part there is a simple HTML input which has data-bind type "textInput" (see more at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html).

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.readOnlyText = "+1";
  this.editableText = ko.observable();
  this.value = ko.observable(this.readOnlyText);
  
  this.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if((newValue.length < this.readOnlyText.length) || 
      (newValue.indexOf(this.readOnlyText) != 0)) {
     this.value(this.readOnlyText);
        this.editableText("");
        return;
    }
    
    this.editableText(newValue.substring(this.readOnlyText.length, (newValue.length)));
  }, this);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: value" />
```

ViewModel is also pretty simple. There are three variables.
readOnlyText - part of string which is read-only.
editableText - an observable which holds a value of editable text.
value - an observable which holds a value of whole text box.

Variable value has a subscription where I check for a condition and set variable value and editableText if needed.

Comment: Hi, i have tried this but it is throwing this error     Uncaught TypeError: newValue.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Hi, could you describe what exactly was your input? I tried jsFiddle with various inputs and i did not encouter any errors in my console. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind natively on the input and its behaviour, you should allow knockout to handle it using the proper knockout framework stuff.
What you need is a special type of observable, called computedObservable.
In fact what you want to do is to provide custom methods for its read/write behaviour

Create a VM, bind it to your html, add a simple value binding on your input and target an observable in your VM, lets call it `userInput`;

So inside your VM:

```
this.userInput = ko.observable('');

 this.userInputComp = ko.pureComputed({
            read: function () {
                return "This always stays here " + this.userInput();
            },
            write: function (value) {
                this.userInput(value);
            },
            owner: this
        });
```

then apply a data-bind on your input like this:

```
data-bind="value: userInputComp "
```

More stuff can be found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)